# cross domain jsonp request.. what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain, jsonp

I am really lost here, and I have no idea what I am doing wrong. 
I have exposed an api which gives a json output, and I want to fetch this data from another domain. Since jsonp is way to go, I am trying the code below.. Inspection on firebug shows that the response to the request is proper JSON, but the callback functions never seem to execute. Any help?

```
$(function(){
    console.log('aa');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://domain/api.php',
        data: {f:'get_total_playtime',userid:'1',starttime:'2011-01-01',endtime:'2011-12-12'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
            console.log('suceess');
            alert(data.time);
        },
        failure: function(data){
            console.log('failure');
        }
    });


});
```

If this is not the right way to go about it, can anyone explain the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Inspection on firebug shows that the response to the request is proper JSON

Then that is the problem. You have to return [JSONP](http://www.json-p.org/), not JSON.

Comment: yes! that did it! i just had to encapsulate a function call around the output. thanks a ton!